# What metric is used to measure estrogen levels?

Tags: blood-tests, endocrinology, estrogen

I have had a blood test recently and over the phone I was told by a doctorthat my oestrogen level is high. I'm a man and was told my level is "190, but the average is 150". 190 what? I forgot to ask and now I am left wondering.

I have googled this but can't seem to find a relevant answer as Google says a healthy level for men is below 20-55 pg/mL, but this can't be using the same metric.

Comment: You should call the lab that did the test and ask what the reference range that they use for their test is, including units of measurement.  You also need to know what kind of estrogen that they measured - estradiol, estrone, etc. That makes a difference.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Alright, will do. Could you make an educated guess as to what "average" they may be referring to or could it be anything? I will contact them as soon as possible but it will have to be next week

Comment: I’ll second what @DoctorWhom has said. My local lab uses the units `pmol/L` for oestradiol, with a reference range for men of 28-156 pmol/L. This is different from the units you found on Google. Not only do assays and units vary, but each lab will have its own reference ranges due to calibration. As an aside, “molar” units (e.g. mol) are related to mass units (e.g. g) based on the molecular mass of what is being tested for.

Comment: I'd add that interpreting male estrone and estradiol levels is pretty complicated. Depending on the clinical question the test was taken to answer, the laboratory reference range may not be helpful in and of itself. Androgen levels, binding protein levels, and other factors may need to be taken into account. It's not just a matter of "this level is low, normal, or high". You're going to need to have a conversation with whomever ordered the test.